# If statement with multiple condition work wrong

Tags: shell

I have a script c shell with following condition:

```
if [ -d ${COOLDIR}/cool_${Today}/daily ] && [ "${CASENAME}" = "D" ]    
then    
    echo "daily dir"    
fi    
if [ -d ${COOLDIR}/cool_${Today}/weekly ] && [ "${CASENAME}" = "W" ]    
then    
    echo "weekly dir"    
fi    
if [ -d ${COOLDIR}/cool_${Today}/monthly ] && [ "${CASENAME}" = "M" ]    
then    
    echo "monthly dir"    
fi
```

If daily directory exists, and I have to run the script for weekly, provide CASENAME = "W", it goes to daily directory anyway.

I am using AIX and Bourne shell

Comment: What's in `Today` variable?  Also, are you using csh or sh?

Comment: What do you mean by "it goes to daily directory anyway"? Could you describe the expected behavior?

Comment: Today is = today's day , for example 20170309. If I provide casename = "W" I expect it top go to to second if statement and print weekly dir. But it goes to first if and prints daily dir. Even I checked pwd is weekly directory. Is something wrong with my if condition?

Comment: What's there in `COOLDIR` variable?  Pass your script through [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net)

Comment: The script have 1000 lines

Comment: That's all the more reason to use shellcheck!

Comment: You should add `echo "($Today) ($CASENAME)"` just before your 3 `if` and give us the output.